# Auth Dialog doesn't work on Ticker and Timeline links

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, authentication

I have an application that publish an open graph action (news.reads).
When someone who doesn't have the app installed click on the icon it should open the Auth Dialog.
Instead I have two scenarios:

1. Into the timeline nothing happens, or a loading popup is showed. The auth dialog never appears and the user is not redirected to the article too.
2. Into the ticker the user receives an error message:

> API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter  Error
>   Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted

example of url with error: https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=289255557788943&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=%2Fconnect%2Fuiserver.php%3Fapp_id%3D289255557788943%26method%3Dpermissions.request%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fg1.globo.com%252Fplaneta-bizarro%252Fnoticia%252F2012%252F03%252Fbritanicos-faturam-mais-de-r-85-mil-vendendo-anuncios-em-seus-rostos.html%253Ffb_action_ids%253D372579739430867%2526fb_action_types%253Dnews.reads%2526fb_source%253Dother_multiline%26response_type%3Dcode%26display%3Dasync%26perms%3Doffline_access%252Cemail%252Cpublish_actions%252Cuser_birthday%252Cuser_religion_politics%252Cuser_relationships%252Cuser_hometown%252Cuser_likes%26auth_referral%3D1&response_type=code&display=async&perms=offline_access%2Cemail%2Cpublish_actions%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_religion_politics%2Cuser_relationships%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_likes&auth_referral=1

If the user access the canvas page of the app directly the auth dialog appears correctly.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test that you see the same functionality on www.beta.facebook.com - if you so, file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs